# getting stdclass object out of array with base64 encoded string

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have a array here with std class object inside a `$imagez`

```
array(2) (
  [0] => stdClass object {
    ID => (string) 44
    Owner => (string) 675
    relatesto => (string) userid
    name => (string) images.jpg
    type => (string) image/jpeg
    size => (string) 2424
    image_heading => (string) ffffff
    image => (string)
    INSERT_DT => (string) 2016-11-08 13:08:25
    UPDATE_DT => null
    ORIG_ID => (string) 44
  }
  [1] => stdClass object {
    ID => (string) 45
    Owner => (string) 675
    relatesto => (string) userid
    name => (string) masnad.jpg
    type => (string) image/jp...
```

I normally use `$images = json_decode(json_encode($imagez), true);` but for some odd reason it does not work, and returns `$images` as `null` and if I even try to do it in this way `$images = json_decode(json_encode($imagez[0]), true);` I still get a `null` value, but normally it would get me the arrays without the stdClass object. So not sure why its going wrong.  base64 encoded strings containing string in `image =>(string)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case it is better to use object notation `->`. So a simple `foreach` will do the trick.

```
//Create a array
$storeimage = array();
foreach ($images as $image){
        $storeimagez[] = $image->ID;
        $storeimagez[] = $image->Owner;
        $storeimagez[] = $image->relatesto;
        // and so on 

}
```